# Glow Effect on a Bitmap set as Background of a custom view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a Class extending View class. I have set the background in XML which is being called as setBackgroundDrawable(getBackground()) in my onDraw() method. This background in 3 concentric circles.

I have the radius for each concentric circle and i am drawing a small orange colored touchCircle when user touches in any of the ring using canvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, touchRadius, mTouchPaint); .
My question is i want to show a glow effect on both sides of the touch Circle within the ring(on which onTouch operation is performed). That means, suppose if the user touches in 3rd ring, a glow effect will be produced of some color around the touchCircle. It will travel from the touch circle to some distance(on both sides of touchCircle) within the ring and then fades out.

I have calculated the angle substended by the touch cordinate with respect to centre(0-360 degrees). My thinking is i will increase/decrease the angle (for left and right glow). But i am confused as in how the glow effect will be produced in the background image. 
Can anyone please guide how to proceed further on this .

Comment: you probably need android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter

Comment: can you please show some images of what you need to do? maybe a sketch?

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow.. cant post images.. but background is an image of three concentric circles. Each concentric ring has rainbow color i.e mix of colors. so when a touch event is done.. i will need to get RGB value of the cordinate , after getting background image in a bitmap. After that i need to show a glow(that the touched color glow travelling through the ring , starting from the point touched in both directions. I am stuck as in how to produce the glow effect)

Comment: @pskink , i think blurmask filter wont do the thing.. as i need to glow the whole area(travelling color effect) with the exact color..

Comment: post a link to an image

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?sa=X&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbnid=B0MGDYsuAmWJBM:&imgrefurl=http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Geometry/Chapter_7&docid=QfLlw-86VQgfAM&imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/b/be/Concentric_Circles.jpg&w=357&h=357&ei=B1hQUqyfONHjrAei64HYDQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:1,s:0,i:90&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=176&tbnw=187&start=0&ndsp=12&tx=54&ty=68

Comment: kind of this ... but a mixture of color is filled in every ring ... will get the RGB values by extracting color from event.getX() and event.getY() aftr user touches in any ring..